# PHP Code replace whit Regular expressions

Tags: php, replace, expression

I have my site on series, usually all series are divided by seasons and episodes, I have the following string: 
The Mentalist S05E14

`where **S05E14** is like **Episode 14 Season 05**` I need to change the expression:

```
**S05E14** 
   for 
**05x14**
```

Also, for any season and episode, so I would remove "S" and replace the "E" for "x"

How can I do this using regular expressions or perhaps otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace( '/S(\d+)E(\d+)/', '\1x\2', $str );
```

Link on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/fE8xKHbS).

Comment: This answer is exactly like mine and was entered about 2 mins after my answer :)

Comment: @anubhava I used the entire name of episode. :P

Comment: `/S(\d+)E(\d+)/i` this is the regex I had used and you can see your answer now :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/S(\d+)E(\d+)/i', '$1x$2', 'S05E14');
```

**[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/amVU9C)**

Answer (score 0):

2 ways without regular expressions

```
$e = 'S05E14';
echo implode( 'x', explode( 'E', substr( $e, 1 ) ) );
echo str_replace( array( 'S', 'E' ), array( '', 'x' ), $e );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string_val="The Mentalist S05E14";
$data = explode(' ', $text);
$count = count($data);
$last_word = $data[$count-1];
$newStr = str_replace("S", "", $last_word);
$newStr = str_replace("E", "x", $newStr);
```

Comment: The string is bigger than just `"S05E14"`. This will replace any S and E.